# Assertion Check for SoapUi response

Tags: soapui, assertion

Considering `SoapUI` response for summary request, we have same `xml` tag in the response coming multiple times.

How do we check if any of the tag is returning incorrect data in the response?

For example:
I have `provideridentifier` in the `xml` tag coming multiple times; I want to check whether any of this particular tag is having `null` response or not in contains assertion.

`"[^0]"` is not working in this case.

Comment: Better use script assertions and xpath. Contains can give you false positive

Answer (score 0):

Use Script Assertion to validate 'provideridentifier' tags as mentioned in below example :

`def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def resHolder = new XmlHolder(response)
def provideridentifiers = resHolder.getNodeValues("//provideridentifier") //Xpath
for(i=0; i<provideridentifiers.size(); i++){
  assert provideridentifiers[i] != null : "provideridentifier field should not be null"
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XPath Match assertion to count the number of empty `provideridentifier` elements:

`count(//provideridentifier[not(normalize-space())])`

For example:

[image]

This assertion expects there to be no empty `provideridentifier` elements and will fail if at least one is found.

I don't know what your XML payload looks like, so these tests use a cut-down version:

**XPath returns `2`**:

```
<test>
    <provideridentifier></provideridentifier>
    <provideridentifier/>
    <provideridentifier>value</provideridentifier>
</test>
```

**XPath returns `2`**:

```
<test>
    <provideridentifier></provideridentifier>
    <provideridentifier/>
</test>
```

**XPath returns `0`**:

```
<test>
    <provideridentifier>value</provideridentifier>
</test>
```

**XPath returns `0`**:

```
<test/>
```